# Django Read more, Read less text

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to display only a part of the Overview initially and after clicking Read more, the rest is displayed.

I have this implementation of Read more - Read less in Django:

HTML:

```
<p><strong>Overview:</strong>
   <span class="overview">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A"|slice:"300"}}</span>
   {% if game.overview|length > 300 %}
     <span class="dots">...</span>
     <span class="more" style="display: none;">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A"|slice:"300:" }}</span>
    <button class="read-button" onclick="readMore(this)">[Read more...]</button>
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function readMore(button) {
  var parent = button.parentNode;
  var dots = parent.querySelector(".dots");
  var moreText = parent.querySelector(".more");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    button.innerHTML = "[Read more...]";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    button.innerHTML = "[Read less...]";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

My problem is that when the text get's sliced inside a word like in this example:

> Created in Unity, and designed to be played in-browser, players make a
> series of moral and dialogue choices within each chapter, before being
> presented a larger question at the end of eac ... [Read more...]

When I am clicking the [Read more...], the output is like this and the word 'each' get's separated where the slice occurred.:

> Created in Unity, and designed to be played in-browser, players make a
> series of moral and dialogue choices within each chapter, before being
> presented a larger question at the end of eac h chapter, asking what
> should happen next in the story.

What should I do so that when the slicing happens inside a word it is not separated when clicking the button.

Comment: What have you tried to resolev the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this really a JS or HTML problem when Django generates the shortened text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem! Just in case someone has a similar issue, this is how I managed to do it:

HTML:

```
<p><strong>Overview:</strong>
      <span class="overview">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A"|truncatewords_html:"50" }}</span>
      <span class="full-text" style="display: none;">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A" }}</span>
      <button class="read-button" onclick="readMore(this);">[Read more...]</button>
    </p>
```

JS:

```
function readMore(button) {
    var parent = button.parentNode;
    var truncatedText = parent.querySelector(".overview");
    var fullText = parent.querySelector(".full-text");

  if (truncatedText.style.display === "none") {
      truncatedText.style.display = "inline";
      fullText.style.display = "none";
      button.innerHTML = "[Read more...]";
  } else {
      truncatedText.style.display = "none";
      fullText.style.display = "inline";
      button.innerHTML = "[Read less...]";
    }
  }
```